# Using GET method for Id

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

My app is working GET method for all Employees.
But I would like to get only Employee like ID.
Web app doesn't call GET method by ID. I don't know why???

I have writtenJS code from angularjs:

```
$scope.edit = function(id){
        console.log('Pass');
        $http.get('/autoeshop/employees' + id, data, config).then(function(response){
            $scope.id = response['data']['id'];
            $scope.name = response['data']['name'];
            $scope.age = response['data']['age'];
            $scope.dept = response['data']['department'];

            $(".addButton").hide();
            $(".updateButton").show();
            $('#myModalLabel').text("Edit Employee details");
            $('#myModalNorm').modal();
        });
```

How can I resolved this? Thanks.

Comment: Missing a slash between `employees` text and `id` value: `'/autoeshop/employees/' + id`. That of course assumes server handles such REST requests.

Comment: Ohhh! You are right!
Thank you.